# getting a TypeError: "v.replace is not a function" while using cypress select with index

Tags: typescript, testing, select, cypress

I have a select in my html which looks something like this

```
<select testId="selectSth" name="select"> 
    <option value="someValue">some Value</option>
    <option value="someOtherValue">some Other Value</option>
    <option value="somethingelse">somethingelse</option>
</select>
<button testId="buttonNext" title="Next">
    <span>Next</span>
</button>
```

since the content of the select is generated dynamically, i try to select the first value and click the next-button via cypress with this code:

```
cy.get('[testId=selectSth]').select(0);
cy.get('[testId=buttonNext]').click();
```

but i am getting an TypeError at the select(0) step: **TypeError: v.replace is not a function** with the following stacktrace

```
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150908:19)
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Context.select (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:150904:45)
    at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169833:24)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168527:18)
From previous event:
    at runCommand (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168506:11)
    at next (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168649:17)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168678:19)
```

I have also been able to call the select call with a specific value, and it all worked. It just doesn't seem to work with indexes.

```
cy.get('[testId=selectSth]').select('someValue');
cy.get('[testId=buttonNext]').click();
```

but i really don't want to do it with exact values. Does anyone know why the TypeError occurs?

Comment: Is that select list accurate? I'm wondering if you have an option with some attribute that is not parsable by `String.prototype.replace()`.

Comment: my actual list in the code contains a mix of numbers and letters, so that shouldn't be the problem.